# Como preencher um formulário em html dinâmico

Tags: html, c#

Boa noite pessoal.

Estou com uma dúvida aqui, eu dificilmente mexo com web, mas precisei montar um arquivo html que tem como objetivo a impressão de um boleto. O projeto é feito em C# e o arquivo html está junto ao projeto. Eu preciso, de alguma forma, jogar o dado que está na modelagem (model) para o html criado.

Parte do html:

```
   <p style="margin: 0; "><b>ESTADO</b><br/><!-- Estado Aqui --></p>
```

Eu preciso, da modelagem, inserir, por exemplo, o "SP" e preencher no lugar desse campo 'Estado Aqui'
O projeto tem uma modelagem com campos de endereço.

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Como esse arquivo é servido? É uma página asp.net ou um stream com o html?

Comment: É um arquivo a parte para a impressão de documento que fiz usando HTML puro. Não montei em asp e nem mvc. Não imaginava que eu iria usar página html. Agora que preciso, só usando asp.net para manipular com dados no html? Não teria uma outra forma? Se tiver um tutorial que me ajudasse na Net.

Comment: O servidor lê o arquivo do disco? Se sim, não tem como (sem fazer nada mirabolante), pois o arquivo seria estático. Você encontra na net milhões de tutoriais de asp.net e php que é o adequado para páginas dinâmicas.

Comment: Esse arquivo html é gerado pelo programa apenas para impressão ou está num servidor?

Comment: Então, não tem uso de servidor nenhum, bom, não vejo utilidade pois não terá uso de banco de dados, por enquanto.

Comment: O html já é uma página, que eu preciso jogar somente os dados que faltam pra ele. Ele não está num servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Sua página modelo:

```html
<!-- modelo.html -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
... etc ...

<p style="margin: 0; "><b>ESTADO</b><br/>|!@[ESTADO]@!|</p>

... etc ...

</html>
```

Então em c# vc chama:

```cs
// Coloque em cima: using System.Web; using System.Text; using System.IO;

var html = File.ReadAllText("modelo.html");

html.Replace("|!@[ESTADO]@!|", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<O ESTADO A SER INSERIDO>"));

File.WriteAllText("saida.html", html, Encoding.UTF8);
```

O padrão "|!@[ESTADO]@!|" pode ser qualquer coisa, desde que seja único na página e idênticos no html e no código.

Observe a tag <meta> no inicio que indica a codificação em UTF-8, a mesma usada ao salvar o arquivo de saída, é importante setar essa tag para evitar que apareçam aqueles caracteres de ponto de interrogação.

Observe também o uso de `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, para codificar o texto nos padrões do HTML.

Existem diversas maneiras de se fazer isso mas essa é uma maneira rápida e com poucas linhas de código.

Comment: Opa, obrigado ae amigão. Segui seus passos e deu certinho. Fico grato mesmo pela ajuda e tempo dedicado. Muito obrigado a todos ae.